# jQuery live ckechbox checked

Tags: jquery

Суть вопроса такова:
есть checkbox, который динамически генерируется javascript'ом. Надо получить его checked состояние. Собственно вопрос, как это сделать? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var el = $("#checkbox_id");
el.attr('checked'); // true - если отмечен, false если нет
```

Comment: у меня если выбран, возвращает checked, если не выбран - undefined. :) Ну в прочем, главное, что работает. спасибо. :)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста, то что undefined это ерунда, но, если вам все-же принципиально всегда иметь именно boolean значения - напишите чето типа

     function getCheckedState( el ){
         return !!el.attr('checked');
     }

И будет вам только true или false, хотя, конечно, вряд-ли вам это нужно :D

Пожалуйста

Comment: Всё правильно, но хотел добавить, что для проверки состояни лучше использовать метод <a href="http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BE_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8">.prop()</a> вместо .attr()

Comment: Солидарен, просто забыл как называется метод

Comment: Нужно пользоваться либо ``.prop("checked")`` либо ``.is(":checked")``. Если использовать ``attr("checked")``, то надо иметь в виду, что некоторые плагины (например jqueryui Button, примененные к чекбоксам) могут подменять элементы, не трогая атрибуты и ``prop`` будет работать, а ``attr`` не будет.

Comment: То что какой-то плагин что0либо подменяет не входит в спецификацию jquery, то что действительно лучше использовать prop а не attr я уже написал, причина этому не та которую описали вы, она намного проще и заключается в том что `attr` работает намного медленее (хотя в этом случае эти медленее ни разу не важны)

C UI не работал и, судя по тому что вы написали, оно и к лучшему, кстати - на jquery тоже наверное с по года ничего серьезного не писал, так что если где не прав - поправте

Comment: ну это просто дополнение было, не говорил, что это ошибка. Просто атрибут не является достаточным условием для галки. В документации разбирают случай с attr и prop. что галка может стоять или не стоять, при этом атрибут checked будет задан в обоих случаях. вопрос тут не столько в плагинах, просто с плагином точно будут проблемы с получением галки. так что либо псевдоклассом :checked либо prop("checked") будет более корректным способом. проблема с обратной совместимостью jquery, в которых функции prop нету и изза этого используют attr, в итоге можно после апгрейда jquery наткнуться на такой ба